# Unfold a drop down menu and click on an entry

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium and chrome webdriver in order to save the configuration of a HP switch without crontab like features.

I'm able to access the GUI and to log in it, but i'm unable to unfold a menu in order to access to the backup button (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcU6j.png)

When i inspect the "maintenance" element, it seems that it is linked with the code below :(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDEfV.png)

I have tried to interact with the "Maintenance" dropdown menu in various ways: by XPATH, By ID, by displayed text, but nothing happen.

There is my selenium script in python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://xx.xx.xx.xx/")

btn_parametre_avancees = driver.find_element(By.ID, "details-button")
btn_parametre_avancees.click();

link_continuer = driver.find_element(By.ID, "proceed-link")
link_continuer.click();

login = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'inputUsername').send_keys("xxx")

password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'inputPassword').send_keys("xxx")

link_login = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="signinForm"]/div[3]/button')
link_login.click();
```

Did you have ideas?

Thanks you in advance !

Comment: Use Action Chains - https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#:~:text=None)%5Bsource%5D-,ActionChains%20are%20a%20way%20to%20automate%20low%20level%20interactions%20such,over%20and%20drag%20and%20drop. to interact with the menu items.

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code/HTML as text and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML you provided, it looks like the XPath below will work

```
//span[text()='Maintenance']
```

Basically we're looking for a SPAN tag that contains the text, "Maintenance". We want to wait for that element to be clickable using [`ExpectedConditions`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) and then click it. That should open that portion of the left nav menu. After that, we'll want to wait for the "Backup and Update Files" (or whatever) menu element to be clickable and then click it. This gives the page some time for the Maintenance submenu to open and be usable.

Additional suggestions...

1. If you aren't going to use the variable for an element more than once, there's no need to create it, e.g.

   ```
   btn_parametre_avancees = driver.find_element(By.ID, "details-button")
   btn_parametre_avancees.click();
   ```

   can be simplified to

   ```
   driver.find_element(By.ID, "details-button").click();
   ```
2. `.send_keys()` doesn't return anything so assigning a variable to it's return does nothing, e.g.

   ```
   login = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'inputUsername').send_keys("xxx")
   ```

   The variable assignment should be removed leaving

   ```
   driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'inputUsername').send_keys("xxx")
   ```

Implementing these suggestions and adding the code to handle the Maintenance and other menus, we have the below

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://xx.xx.xx.xx/")

driver.find_element(By.ID, "details-button").click();
driver.find_element(By.ID, "proceed-link").click();
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'inputUsername').send_keys("xxx")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'inputPassword').send_keys("xxx")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="signinForm"]/div[3]/button').click();

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Maintenance']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Backup and Update Files']"))).click()
```

Comment: If this does not work, please give me the full error message and indicate on what line the failure occurred.